# running_an_app_with_opencv_32bit_lib_on_x86_64_android

Tags: android, opencv

Can I use "adb install" command to install an app intended for 32bit systems on my x86_64 Marshmallow system?

The app has opencv implementation only for x86 (because it uses opencv 2.4) which means that the libopencv_java.so libraries files is only in the 'lib\x86' directory inside the .apk file (There are other subdirectories of 'lib' directory without library files inside).

I'm not too good with Android system, so the question may seem credulous to some of you, but please help me if you can - I really need to install this app on my smartphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 64b Android can run the 32b applications in compatibility mode (at least the ARM for sure, but I think x86 too, otherwise many of old legacy applets in market would be not working on 64b OS).

To make sure the 32b .apk works in emulated 32b mode, it has to contain **ONLY 32b libs variants**. If you have multiple native libraries from different vendors, some with 32b support only, and some with 64b support included, delete the 64b variants everywhere (but make sure those libs do have 32b variant, although that would be again a bit insane, to release anything for 64-only).

The true 32b OS will not mind 64b libraries, so rather validate manually by checking the zip (apk) content. Only 64b OS will be confused if some libraries are 64b and others are not.

Such .apk with valid set of libraries should work both when installed from GooglePlay market, or by `adb install some.apk` from PC.

Why didn't you simply try to install it? Or does it fail and how? If it fails and you think the 32b libs are the problem, verify the 64b libs folders are non-empty, so some other library triggers 64b mode. If they are empty, the app should work, and any other problem is probably unrelated to 32b opencv.

Comment: Thanks Ped7g!!! For any of you interested in making a legacy app (using opencv 2.4.x libraries) work on (probably) any 64 bit architecture: delete ALL files in 'lib' 'arm64-v8a', 'mips64' and x86_64' subdirectories and make sure 'libopencv_java.so' libraries file is present in the 32 bit variant for the target 64 bit architecture. I copied the missing libraries file from 'OpenCV-2.4.11-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\libs\armeabi' unpacked sdk file using APK Easy Tool - it worked like a charm